# What is /usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.31/bin/g[

Tags: homebrew, gnu-coreutils

What is `/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.31/bin/g[`?

`g[` is an odd file name.

It obviously appears to have been installed by the homebrew coreutils formula, but I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a remark when installing `coreutils`:

```
Commands also provided by macOS have been installed with the prefix "g".
```

Presumably what was once `[` is now `g[`.

`[` is an odd name for a file, but it's an important shell feature. See `man \[` for details.

Comment: I (obviously wrongly) expected punctuation to be builtins instead of separate commands…

Comment: This may be so that if you're using `sh` then you can do `bash`-like things such as `[ ... ]` on the command-line where that's equivalent to `test ...` and the `]` is eaten as an argument.

Comment: @XDR The `[` command is a builtin in at least bash, zsh, and ksh. But `/bin/[` is there as well, it's just overridden by the builtins.